# How to generate phone numbers?

Tags: python

Create a `gen_number()` function that generates a phone number with code 0888 _ _ _ _ _ _. The numbers that you can generate can only contain the numbers 5, 6, 8, 0, 3, 4. Example: 0444506345

Is it possible to do that, without `import random`?
and how to do it with `import random`?

I tried this:

```py
def gen_numbers(indx = '+0888',allowed = '6, 5, 8 ,0, 3, 4'):
    phones = []
    for phnmbr in range(1, 10):
        res = indx + allowed
    print(gen_numbers)


gen_numbers()
```

but output was: `[]`

I know that I'm doing wrong, but idk what

Comment: Why do you not want to `import random`? Do you mean you want the generator to generate the same number every time?

Comment: There are five variables in the `gen_numbers()` function. Each is assigned a value but only `indx` and `allowed` are ever read (into `res`, which is promptly discarded as well). Start with having *one* variable to create your phone number in and then print or return it.

Answer (score 0):

sure! I can help you create a gen_number() function that generates a phone number with the given format using the specified digits. Let's start with the implementation without using the random module:

Without using random module:

```
def gen_number():
    digits = [5, 6, 8, 0, 3, 4]
    number = '0888'

    for _ in range(6):
        digit = digits[_ % len(digits)]
        number += str(digit)

    return number
```

n this implementation, we have a list of available digits [5, 6, 8, 0, 3, 4], and we append one digit at a time to the number string by cycling through the digits list using the modulo operator.

Now, if you want to achieve the same result using the random module, you can modify the function as follows:

Using random module:

```
import random

def gen_number():
    digits = [5, 6, 8, 0, 3, 4]
    number = '0888'

    for _ in range(6):
        digit = random.choice(digits)
        number += str(digit)

    return number
```

Comment: FYI: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
import random

def gen_numbers():
    allowed_numbers = '658034'
    indx = '+0888'
    for i in range(6):
        indx += allowed_numbers[random.randint(0, len(allowed_numbers) - 1)]
    return indx

print(gen_numbers())
```

Comment: And thank to u so much!!!

Comment: There’s also simply `random.choice`…

Answer (score 0):

The choice() function from the random module is ideal for this.

You can also make your function more flexible by doing something like this:

```
from random import choice

def gen_numbers(n: int=1, prefix: str='+0888', choices: str='658034', length: int=10):
    lst = []

    for _ in range(n):
        suffix = [choice(choices) for _ in range(length)]
        lst.append(prefix+''.join(suffix))
    
    return lst

print(gen_numbers(n=5))
```

In this way you can specify how many numbers you want to generate, what the prefix should be, a string of numbers that can be used and how long the suffix should be.

**Sample output:**

```
['+08880433680660', '+08880856345883', '+08888644584488', '+08886845040884', '+08888086386653']
```

Answer (score -2):

```python
# import module
import random as r

ph_no = []

ph_no.append(0)
for i in range(1,4):
    ph_no.append(8)
for i in range(4, 11):
    ph_no.append(r.randint(0, 9))

# printing the number
for i in ph_no:
    print(i, end="")
```

I know the code is inefficient but yes here's the answer

Comment: *”The numbers that you can generate can only contain the numbers 5, 6, 8, 0, 3, 4”*…

Comment: and thank to u so much too